# Output categories in something different than a list

Tags: list, categories

I wanted to output all my categories in the sidebar of my wordpress theme. Now I use the function `wp_list_categories();` which works fine. However it always displays the categories in a list and I don't want that.

What I want is to display the categories as links so that they are inline elements. I could stay with the list and just style them as inline elements by applying `display: inline-block;` to the list items. I guess it is semantically correct, too.

So is there a way of getting rid of the list in WordPress or should I stay with my approach? And is it semantically correct?

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you had a look at the [*Display Categories Assigned to a Post* example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Examples) in [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) in the Codex. This should give you a very good idea on how to modify your own code. This is just my simplistic way to achieve what you want. Feel free to modify as needed

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';
$separator = ', ';

if ( !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```